# Excel - Look for duplicates in column A and then look to the right of duplicates and see if they're different

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'm trying to locate duplicates in column A but then look for mismatches in column b. I'm struggling to figure out how to accomplish this using excel formulas.

Thanks in advance.

**Example Scenario**

`COLUMN A  |  COLUMN B  |  Duplicate w/ mismatch
  AA      |   001      |
  AA      |   001      |
  BB      |   002      |
  BB      |            |  Duplicate with mismatch column B found!
  CC      |   003      |
  CC      |   003      |
  CC      |   004      |  Duplicate with mismatch column B found!`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In **C2** enter:

```
=IF(A2<>A1,"",IF(B1=B2,"","Duplicate with mismatch column B found!"))
```

and copy down.